# Velocity of rocket thrown fuel box less that previous thrown fuel box's velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, rocket-science

I have been reading the following paper "[Correction to the Traditional Ideal Rocket Thrust Equation](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/144851683.pdf)" and there's one thing at the end that I don't get to understand.

[image]

In the footnote of the image, the author states:

> After each throw, the rocket moves faster in S, opposing $ w_{rel} $, so the next thrown box’s velocity in $ S $ is less than that of the previous one, so each box carries away less momentum in $ S $, despite all having the same $ w_{rel} $.

S, being the inertial ground frame, and $ w_{rel} $ the velocity of the fuel relative to the rocket.

This doesn't seem to make any sense as the exhaust velocity is constant (-18 m/s in his example), and the rocket velocity is increasing, so the fuel velocity respect the inertial frame, S,  should be increasing over time, and the momentum of the fuel, respectively, increases as well.

Am I missing something or is the author wrong?

Comment: If the rocket starts from rest, is a box ejected from the rocket at that moment defined to have positive or negative velocity/momentum in the S frame?

Comment: In a picture on the first page, he draws the rocket moving to the right, and that's positive. So, I assume the momentum of the box is negative with respect to S